# JSON error with coffeescript & Rails asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

I am using Rails 3.2.14 without issue...

I have recently renamed `application.js` to `application.js.coffee` and am now getting a JSON error.

```
JSON::GeneratorError

only generation of JSON objects or arrays allowed
  (in /.../app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee)
```

Even when I delete all the contents of `application.js.coffee` I still get the error.

When I try to view it directly (`http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js`), its the same issue:

```
throw Error("JSON::GeneratorError: only generation of JSON objects or arrays allowed\n  (in /.../app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee)")
```

I have combed my app for any potential issues but everything looks pretty standard.

Comment: Does application.js.coffee has references to other JS as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar problem ([Rails 4 asset pipeline throws "only generation of JSON objects or arrays allowed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18399655/rails-4-asset-pipeline-throws-only-generation-of-json-objects-or-arrays-allowed)), which had nothing to do with application.js. The multi_json gem got updated from 1.7.8 to 1.7.9, and broke my app. Any change to the cofeescript-files resulted in this "only generation of JSON objects or arrays allowed" error.

I explicitly put the multi_json gem in my Gemfile, fixed to version 1.7.8. In solved the problem for me.

Comment: There also seems to be something going on with using Pow.  When i started the server with WebBrick and Thin, both worked ok.  But using multi_json seemed to allow it to work with Pow as well. Thanks!

Comment: @brewster are you using execjs gem? If you are using, you have to use Ruby >= 2.0.0 to run correctly.

Comment: exec_js 2.0.1 should fix the issue.

Answer (score 5):

I have the save issue not in a Rails project, but a ruby project using sprockets.
I have not finally determined the problem, but it seems to be related to execjs and the Javascript runtime used.

You can try to add

`gem 'therubyracer'`

to your Gemfile. This installs the v8 engine, which solved the problem for me.

Comment: This solved it for me on Ubuntu 13.04, nvm, Node 0.10.12. Execjs was using said Node installation before before I added 'therubyracer'. (The multi_json suggestion in the other answer didn't work.) What OS/Node do you have?

Comment: I tried downgrading execjs to an earlier version thanks to [this blog](http://www.seanbehan.com/json-generatorerror-only-generation-of-json-objects-or-arrays-allowed). That seems to have fixed it for now.