# Rails 4 asset pipeline throws "only generation of JSON objects or arrays allowed"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

This may be related to [JSON error with coffeescript & Rails asset pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394817/json-error-with-coffeescript-rails-asset-pipeline#new-answer)

I'm working on an app in Rails 4. I have an asset called tasks.js.coffee. Until recently everything was fine. This morning I wanted to make a change, and Rails throws "only generation of JSON objects or arrays allowed".

It seems that any change is sufficient to throw the error, even removing a blank line, or changing a single character in a string. When I revert changes it works again.

I'm assuming some gems got updated yesterday when I did a bundle update, causing this problem.

Did anybody else see it? Does anyone know what causes this problem, and how to fix it?

Comment: Found it. The multi_json gem got updated from 1.7.8 to 1.7.9. This causes the problem.
I fixed the version in the Gemfile: gem 'multi_json', '1.7.8'
This solved my problem.

Answer (score 8):

I had to set the execjs version in the Gemfile to 1.4.0: gem 'execjs' '1.4.0'. The recent update to 2.0.0 seems to be the one causing the issue.

Comment: 'execjs' requires (at least) Ruby version 2.0.0 to function correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Update your ruby version to 2.0.0.